# How to make a KOTLIN list with JSON API bracket lists

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to make a list in Kotlin from a JSon API.
I did the tutorial from Udemy, and I made the Weather app. It works perfectly, but now I need to make a new list with an orders list.

Here is the Weather API code :

```json
{
  "query": {
    "results": {
      "channel": {
        "item" : {
          "forecast" : [
            {
              "data": 1
            },
            {
              "data": 1
            },
            {
              "data": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But now I need to make a list, and to take the previous example, it looks like this :

```json
{
  "query": {
    "results": {
      "channel": {
        "item": {
          "forecast": {
            "0": {
              "data": 1
            },
            "1": {
              "data": 1
            },
            "2": {
              "data": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Kotlin code that is working with the first example of API :

```kotlin
// IN FILE WeatherHelp.kt

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("yql?format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
    fun getForecast(@Query("q") q: String) : Call<Weather>
}

class Weather(val query: WeatherQuery)
class WeatherQuery(val results: WeatherResult)
class WeatherResult(val channel: WeatherChannel)
class WeatherChannel(val title: String, val item: WeatherItem)
class WeatherItem(val forecast: List<Forecast>)
class Forecast(val date: String, val day: String, val high: String, val low: String, val text: String)

class WeatherRetriever {
    val service : WeatherAPI

    init {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
        service = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI::class.java)
    }

    fun getForecast(callback : Callback<Weather>, searchTerm : String) {
        var default = searchTerm
        if (searchTerm == "") {
            default = "Paris"
        }
        val q = "select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"${default}\")"
        val call = service.getForecast(q)
        call.enqueue(callback)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// IN FILE ForecastActivity.kt

class ForecastActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forecast)

        val retriever = WeatherRetriever()

        val callback = object : Callback<Weather> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Weather>?, response: Response<Weather>?) {
                println("RESPONSE")

                title = response?.body()?.query?.results?.channel?.title
                println(response?.body()?.query?.results?.channel?.item?.forecast)
                var forecasts = response?.body()?.query?.results?.channel?.item?.forecast

                var forecastStrings = mutableListOf<String>()
                if (forecasts != null) {
                    for (forecast in forecasts) {
                        val newString = "${forecast.date}\nHigh = ${forecast.high} Low = ${forecast.low}\n${forecast.text}"
                        forecastStrings.add(newString)
                    }
                }

                var listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.forecastListView)
                var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@ForecastActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, forecastStrings)
                listView.adapter = adapter
            }


            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Weather>?, t: Throwable?) {
                println("FAILURE")
            }
        }

        val searchTerm = intent.extras.getString("searchTerm")

        retriever.getForecast(callback, searchTerm)
    }
}
```

So I tried to make a list of "forecast" objects, but as you can see it, this does not contains any json array list but keys as "0" and "1" (there is no '[')

I am sure the problem is not the API, as my friend is making the same app but for IOS, and this is working for him.

I suppose that, when more orders will be added, we should have a "4", "5", etc keys and values.

So my question is : How do I create a list (who will be a xml ListView, and will be automatically refreshed) from these kind of objects ?

(Sorry for posting so much code, but I am really stuck on that)

Thank you in advance.